# how to display databse data in table form in laravel5

Tags: laravel-5

i have database table data in object form, like this

```
{"item_id": "1",
"item_color": "Black",
"item_size": "L",
"item_Quantity": "5",},

{"item_id": "2",
"item_color": "white",
"item_size": "M",
"item_Quantity": "5",},

{"item_id": "3",
"item_color": "green",
"item_size": "S",
"item_Quantity": "5",},

{"item_id": "4",
"item_color": "yellow",
"item_size": "S",
"item_Quantity": "5",}
```

i want display the data in table  format.i am searching but i can,t find exact solution.

Answer (score 2):

Something along the lines of:

```
<table>

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Color:</td>
            <td>Size:</td>
            <td>Quantity:</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach($items as $item)
            <tr>
                <td>$item->item_color</td>
                <td>$item->item_size</td>
                <td>$item->item_quantity</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>

</table>
```